# Trying to echo output from 2 radio buttons

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form with an if/else statement and I got the first part to work. It's a radio button for movie rating. If no fields are blank it prints info. But I need to insert another echo depending on whether they said they want to be contacted for a survey and I don't know where to put the code. see below:

```
<fieldset><legend>MOVIE WATCHED AND RATING SURVEY:</legend>

    Please tell us your name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo         $name;?>">
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
    <br><br>
    Please tell us your email address: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?   php echo $email;?>">
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
    <br><br>
    Name one movie you watched recently: <input type="text" name="movie" value="<?php echo $movie;?>">
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $movieErr;?></span>

    <p><label>Please rate the movie:</label></p>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="Very Bad" checked> Very Bad<br>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="Bad"> Bad<br>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="Middle-of-the-Road"> Middle of-the-Road<br>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="Good"> Good<br>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="Very Good"> Very Good<br>
    </form>

    <p><label>Would you like to be contacted again for addtional surveys?</label></p>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="radio" name="survey" value="yes" checked> Yes<br>
        <input type="radio" name="survey" value="no"> No<br>
    </form>

    <p align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit My     Information" /></p>
</fieldset>
</form>

<?php # Program 2 Handle form

// Print the submitted information:
if ( !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) &&    !empty($_POST['movie']) ) {
    echo "Thank you for completing the survey. Here's what you said";
    echo "<p>Your name is {$_POST['name']}";
    echo "<p>Your e-mail address is {$_POST['email']}";
    echo "<p>You recently watched {$_POST['movie']} and felt it was    {$_POST['rating']}!";
    echo "<p>Thank you for agreeing to be contacted for future surveys";
} else { // Missing form value.
    echo '<p>Please go back and fill out all required fields.</p>';
}
?>
```

This is where I am lost. I need to say "Thanks for agreeing to take survey" or "we respect your wish not to" based on what if they entered yes or no on radio button

Comment: forgot to add form code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your HTML needs some work. If all this information should be submitted together, you should only have *one* `<form>` tag around all of it, like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <fieldset><legend>MOVIE WATCHED AND RATING SURVEY:</legend>
        <label for="name">Please tell us your name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name ?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr ?></span>
        <br><br>

        <label for="email">Please tell us your email address: </label>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email ?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr ?></span>
        <br><br>

        <label for="movie">Name one movie you watched recently: </label>
        <input type="text" name="movie" value="<?php echo $movie ?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $movieErr ?></span>

        <p><label for="rating">Please rate the movie:</label></p>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="Very Bad" checked> Very Bad<br>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="Bad"> Bad<br>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="Middle-of-the-Road"> Middle of-the-Road<br>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="Good"> Good<br>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="Very Good"> Very Good<br>

        <p>
            <label for="survey">
                Would you like to be contacted again for addtional surveys?
            </label>
        </p>
        <input type="radio" name="survey" value="yes" checked> Yes<br>
        <input type="radio" name="survey" value="no"> No<br>
        <p align="center">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit My Information" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Then in your PHP, adding the check for the `survey` selection will be pretty easy:

```
// Print the submitted information:
if ( !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['movie']) ) {
    echo "Thank you for completing the survey. Here's what you said";
    echo "<p>Your name is $_POST[name]";
    echo "<p>Your e-mail address is $_POST[email]";
    echo "<p>You recently watched $_POST[movie] and felt it was $_POST[rating]!";

    // add another if here
    if ($_POST['survey'] == 'yes') {
        echo "<p>Thank you for agreeing to be contacted for future surveys";
    } elseif ($_POST['survey'] == 'no') {
        echo "<p>We respect your with not to be contacted for future surveys";
    }

} else { // Missing form value.
    echo '<p>Please go back and fill out all required fields.</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question i think that you want.

```
if(isset($_GET["submit"]))
{
if(isset($_GET["addtional_surveys"])){
    if($_GET["addtional_surveys"]=="Yes"){
        //show your additional survey form here
    }else{
        //movie extra details
    }
}else{
//your form code goes here <form action="" method="get">
}
}else{
     //your form code goes here <form action="" method="get">
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

I think you could benefit from using HTML5. HTML5 will automatically give you a response to the form when it is submitted. You may place "Required" at the end of the  the input. Also you do not need to filter for eg. email any more, HTML 5 does this on the fly. You may find more about this on W3schools.com. In your form part place:

```
<input type="text" name="movie" size="40" maxlength="60" />
<select name="rating" size="3">
<option>Vælg</option>
<option value="0">Very Bad</option>
<option value="1">Bad</option>
<option value="2">Middle-of-the-Road</option>
<option value="3">Good</option>
<option value="4">Very Good</option>
</select>
<p><label>Would you like to be contacted again for addtional surveys?  </label></p>
<input type="radio" name="status" value="YES" checked="checked" />&nbsp;   
<input type="radio" name="status" value="NO" />
```

In your receiving php script place:

```
<?php # Program 2 Handle form
// Print the submitted information:
if ( !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) &&    !empty($_POST['movie']) ) {
    echo "Thank you for completing the survey. Here's what you said";
    echo "<p>Your name is {$_POST['name']}";
    echo "<p>Your e-mail address is {$_POST['email']}";
    echo "<p>You recently watched {$_POST['movie']} and felt it was    {$_POST['rating']}!";
    if ($_POST['status']=='YES') {
        // respondent would like you to come back
        echo "<p>Thank you for agreeing to be contacted for future surveys";
    }else{
        // respondent does not want to particcipate in future surveys
        echo "<p>We respect your wish not to be contacted in the future";
    }
    }else{ // Missing form value.
        echo '<p>Please go back and fill out all required fields.</p>';
    }
```

I have not tested this, but it should work.